# How to add Grand Total in base currency to the PDF invoice?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, invoice, pdf, currency

We are running a 1.9.0.1 install and need to display the grand total base currency value on invoices that have been generated using other currencies than base.
Even better if all the values on the PDF invoice could be displayed in both currencies.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick check on the Models used in the PDF generation and it looks like the following is needed to get what you need:

- Extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default` and rewrite `getItemPricesForDisplay` function, that will give you the option to change the price and subtotal for every line in the invoice.
- Extend `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Pdf_Grandtotal` and rewrite 'getTotalsForDisplay' function in order to add base currency to grandtotal

Your rewrite bit in `config.xml` may look like this:

```
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
            </yourmodule>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_items_invoice_default>Your_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default</order_pdf_items_invoice_default>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
            <tax>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_pdf_grandtotal>Your_Module_Model_Sales_Pdf_Grandtotal</sales_pdf_grandtotal>
                </rewrite>
            </tax>
        </models>
    </global>
    ...
```